# Cant add data to database, 404 not found for mapping

Tags: java, spring

I have two entities, two controllers for that entities, clean java config for spring configuration. One controller for entity works fine, I can add data to database. Second controller, which is same just another entity wont work, I cant add data to database.

This is `EmployeeDetailController class:`

```
  @Controller
@RequestMapping("/employeeDetail")
public class EmployeeDetailController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;


    @GetMapping("/listEmployeeDetail")
    public String listEmployeeDetail(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the service
        List<EmployeeDetail> theEmployeeDetail = employeeService.listEmployeeDetail();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("employeeDetails", theEmployeeDetail);

        return "list-employeeDetail";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForAddEmployeeDetail")
    public String showFormForAddEmployeeDetail(Model theModel) {

        // create model attribute to bind form data
        EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail = new EmployeeDetail();

        theModel.addAttribute("employeeDetail", theEmployeeDetail);

        return "addNewEmployeeDetailForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewEmployeeDetail")
    public String addNewEmployeeDetail(@ModelAttribute("employeeDetail") EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail) {

        // save the customer using our service
        employeeService.addNewEmployeeDetail(theEmployeeDetail);


        return "redirect:/employeeDetail/listEmployeeDetail";
    }

}
```

And this is `addNewEmployeeDetailForm.jsp` part of code for that:

```
    <form:form action="addNewEmployeeDetail" modelAttribute="employeeDetail" method="POST">
```

When I run it, app open me a form to add data, after I click save, its 404 not found.

While this is my another controller:

`EmployeeController:`

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listEmployee(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the service
        List<Employee> theEmployee = employeeService.listEmployee();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("employees", theEmployee);

        return "list-employee";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {

        // create model attribute to bind form data
        Employee theEmployee = new Employee();

        theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);

        return "addNewEmployeeForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewEmployee")
    public String addNewEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee theEmployee) {

        // save the customer using our service
        employeeService.addNewEmployee(theEmployee);


        return "redirect:/employee/list";
    }
}
```

And `addNewEmployeeForm.jsp` part of code for form to add data:

```
    <form:form action="addNewEmployee" modelAttribute="employee" method="POST">
```

That works fine, while first controller doesnt work.

This is my `DemoAppConfig:`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("ets")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());



    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }

        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }


    // need a helper method
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"ets.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

`EmployeeDAOImpl:`

```
 @Override
public void addNewEmployeeDetail(EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail) {

    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theEmployeeDetail);

}
```

`EmployeeServiceImpl:`

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addNewEmployeeDetail(EmployeeDetail theEmployeeDetail) {
    employeeDAO.addNewEmployeeDetail(theEmployeeDetail);
}
```

I noticed that in my entity class `EmployeeDetails` constructor:

```
public EmployeeDetail(int workExperience, String hobby, String nationality) {
    this.workExperience = workExperience;
    this.hobby = hobby;
    this.nationality = nationality;
}
```

is never used. While constructor from entity `Employee` is used.

`SQL`

```
     use `etsystem`;

create table employee (
   employee_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   last_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   email    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);
 
 
create table employee_detail (
   employee_detail_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
   nationality VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   hobby  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   work_experience  int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (employee_detail_id),
   CONSTRAINT employee_details FOREIGN KEY (employee_detail_id) REFERENCES employee (employee_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: 404 error means that he can't find this page "list-employeeDetail". Check your database for making sure that your data has been saved or not. If not share your service logic for storing data into the database.

Comment: Data is not saved in database after I click save. I updated question with logic for storing data into the database.